# How can I play video from byte array, and not allow user get the raw file?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My question is I store encrypted clip file in client. But video player only support video format file.

So I convert byte array in to mp4 file. Anyone can provide a better solution to play byte array?

My current method for trying to do this is:

1. Write byte to a .mp4 file
2. Load and play the .mp4 file by Video Player
3. Delete the temp file after video is playing

It seems works but I'm not sure whether it is safe.

Here is my code:

```
void Start()
{
    byte[] data = EncryptManager.Instance.DecryptData(encryptedData);
    if (data != null){
            WriteByteArrayToFile("temp.mp4", data);
            videoPlayer.url = "temp.mp4";
            videoPlayer.source = VideoSource.Url;
     }
     StartCoroutine(ChekVideoLoading());
}

IEnumerator ChekVideoLoading()
{
    while (!videoPlayer.isPlaying)
    {
        yield return null;
    }
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);
    File.Delete("temp.mp4");
}

public void WriteByteArrayToFile(string fileName, byte[] data)
{
    FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
    fileStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);  
}
```

Comment: is `WriteByteArrayToFile` a method wrote by you? If so please add it. It doesn't seem to come from the Unity API

Comment: OK, I've updated it.

Comment: did you try to access the raw file? Afaik this creates the file in `Application.dataPath` by default which is not visible to a user. Afaik only if you would write to `Application.persitentDataPath` users can access it, You could use [Path.GetFullPath()](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getfullpath?view=netframework-4.6) to `Debug.Log` to verify the location where it gets stored.

Comment: it's just invisible by default. they still can steal data, right?

Comment: usually the built app runs in kind of a sandbox => you don't have access to the OS and the OS doesn't have access (directly) to you. So I don't think so but I might be wrong ^^

Comment: Sorry! I forgot to mention that one of my target platform is windows. it would be easy to access the persistent Data folder

Comment: yeah that's why I didn't say you should write to persitentDtaPath ... I said only if you **would** write there it should be accessable. Simply make a test: Comment out the delete line, build your app for windows, run the code => search on your harddrive for "temp.mp4"

Comment: it cannot be found by search tool! but our clip is pretty valuable. I will try to find the method of least risk. thanks anyway~

Comment: I don't know what kind of clip that is but ... well a user can still capture a screen video while playing it so ...

Comment: A determined user will be able to get their hands on this no matter what. If you're simply storing the file unencrypted on the hard drive (even if its not in an easily accesible location) it's fairly trivial to pull it out.

The real question is why do you care so much about not letting people get the video? You realise they could just use screen-capture tools to record it even if you had some perfect unbeatable encryption to protect it right?

Comment: I'm developing something like a course platform. I can't limit user to use screen capture tool. But it is another story that user discover and pull out the decrypted clip.

Comment: If you don't mind the insane memory requirements, you can use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.memorystream

Comment: Late comment, but you can just use a local HTTP server. It's quick, easy, self contained, and platform agnostic. Find an open-license HTTP server, drop it into your project, tweak it to provide the desired stream (e.g MemoryStream), and simply point your media player at `http://localhost:[port]/...`. Playing from encrypted files is also doable, but you will want to make a custom stream to access the files; this page describes a clean and efficient approach: https://www.boxedapp.com/encrypted_video_streaming.html (just ignore the stuff related to their software lol).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out AVPro player provide [OpenVideoFromBuffer](http://www.renderheads.com/content/docs/AVProVideoClassReference/interface_render_heads_1_1_media_1_1_a_v_pro_video_1_1_i_media_control.html#a412af15b1d7654acbe84782937e9700c) to let me play the binary data directly. But this method is only for windows platform. Hope this information may help somebody.

Comment: Do you think it will solve other junior coders? Please tell me all the code and also where to download this library.

Comment: It is a premium asset. You can purchase it from the unity asset store.